# How to get value of a cell by column name in java using azure-kusto-java library

Tags: java, azure-data-explorer, kusto-java-sdk

```
public KustoResultSetTable executeKustoQuery(ClientImpl client, String query) {

    KustoResultSetTable mainTableResult = null;
    try {
        KustoOperationResult results = client.execute(databaseName, query);
        mainTableResult = results.getPrimaryResults();
    } catch (DataServiceException | DataClientException e) {

        errorHandler(e, "Error while retrieving results from kusto query!");
    }
    return mainTableResult;
}
```

The above code returns me a result of this type

```
Name    | Age
XYZ AAA | 29
```

How can I get the value of 1st row under name column using Azure Kusto Java `mainTableResult` object

Expected String output - `"XYZ AAA"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
if (mainTableResult.first()) {
    int columnIndex = mainTableResult.findColumn("Name")
    return mainTableResult.getString(columnIndex);
} else {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException(""); // Or any other error handling
}
```

A complete version is:

```
public String executeKustoQuery(ClientImpl client, String query) {

    KustoResultSetTable mainTableResult = null;
    try {
        KustoOperationResult results = client.execute("databaseName", query);
        mainTableResult = results.getPrimaryResults();
        if (mainTableResult.first()) {
            int columnIndex = mainTableResult.findColumn("Name")
            return mainTableResult.getString(columnIndex);
        } else {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException(""); // Or any other error handling
        }
    } catch (DataServiceException | DataClientException e) {

        errorHandler(e, "Error while retrieving results from kusto query!");
    }
}
```